# Buffer memory allocation for Dynamic uniform buffer in Vulkan

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-physics, vulkan

I want to split this question into 3 parts:-

1. what is the concept of **limits.minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment** why do we need to use this to get our required alignment and derive the offset of the buffer from it? can't Vulkan distinguish different data types and their respective alignment automatically?
2. in Sascha Willems example he calculates the Dynamic alignment for one 4X4 matrix as follows

   ```
   size_t uboAlignment = vulkanDevice->properties.limits.minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment
   dynamicAlignment = (sizeof(glm::mat4) / uboAlignment) * uboAlignment + ((sizeof(glm::mat4) % uboAlignment) > 0 ? uboAlignment : 0);
   ```

   One 4X4 matrix is 64 bytes and the minimum alignment size allowed is 256 bytes but as far as i know his dynamicAlignment calculation results in (64+256 = 320 //which i believe is not allowed in vulkan) i dont quite get how this **dynamicAlignment** calculation works
3. how this dynamicAlignment variable reflects to

   ```
   VkBufferCreateInfo bufferInfo = {};
   bufferInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
   bufferInfo.size = size;
   ```

   and memory mapping something like

   ```
   void * data;
   vkMapMemory(device, uniformStagingBufferMemory, 0, sizeof(matrix), 0, &data);
   memcpy(data, &matrix, sizeof(matrix));
   vkUnmapMemory(device, uniformStagingBufferMemory);
   copyBuffer(uniformStagingBuffer, uniformBuffer, sizeof(matrix));
   ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The minimum UBO alignment is a restriction *on you*. That is, it tells you that the start of every UBO must be some multiple of that alignment. It tells you where you *must* put your data in memory, in order for the system to use that data.

   That's not something Vulkan can automatically make you do. Vulkan is an explicit API: you live within *its* restrictions, not vice-versa. Note that OpenGL [has the same restriction on UBO data](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object#Limitations).
2. This code is quite broken, but it works by accident. The result of `(sizeof(glm::mat4) / uboAlignment)` is *zero*, because division of integers will always result in *integers*. And since `minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment` is required by the standard to be no less than 256, dividing 64 by this value will *always* produce zero, rounded down. And `0 * uboAlignment` is still zero.

   So the only part of the code left is `((sizeof(glm::mat4) % uboAlignment) > 0 ? uboAlignment : 0)` 64 % 256 is 192, which is > 0, so the result is the `uboAlignment`.

   So it works, but only by accident. He may as well have just used `minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment` directly.
3. First, mapping of memory is a *very* heavyweight operation. You should never map memory just to set a matrix, then immediately unmap it. If you intend to modify memory through mapping, you should keep it mapped until you're ready to delete it. This will not inhibit performance, prevent you from using that memory in accord with the allowed usage methods, or anything else.

   Second, as clearly outlined by the specification, if you create a `VkBuffer` that can be used as a uniform buffer, the offset you specify must adhere to `minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment`. Similarly, when using such a buffer as a UBO resource, the offset you provide *must* be aligned to `minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment` as well, whether the offset is dynamic or static.

Comment: in my scenario i have a vector of mat4 (each with 64 bytes) that has the uniform buffer data of many model matrices, Technically the machine knows that the offset for each element inside the vector is 64 bytes and it's multiples, but iam telling vulkan to offset by 256 bytes for each uniform data inside the vector, how this will work?

Comment: The code in 2 isn't broken, it does exactly what it is supposed to. Ceiling `sizeof(glm::mat4)` to the next multiple of `uboAlignment`. Regardless of the value of `uboAlignment` (which might even have been **smaller** than 64!), or the size of `glm::mat4`.

Comment: @Ext3h: "*which might even have been smaller than 64*" It *cannot* be smaller than 64; the Vulkan specification requires it to be at least 256. Furthermore, it's a highly obtuse way of doing so, since if that's what you wanted, you could just do `std::max(uboAlignment, sizeof(glm::mat4))`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Right, wasn't aware that 256 is the guaranteed minimum. However the use of `std::max` is also plain wrong. If `sizeof(glm::mat4) > uboAlignment && sizeof(glm::mat4) % uboAlignment != 0`, the buffer size would no longer be a multiple of `uboAlignment`. The original code is correct, and a clean way to ensure correct results.

Comment: @Ext3h: If `sizeof(glm::mat4) % uboAlignment != 0`, then that means that the `sizeof` the object in question is not a power of two. And therefore, it's not a valid alignment for Vulkan. So... why are you comparing the size of something which may not be a valid alignment? Basically, I don't see the point of involving `sizeof(glm::mat4)` in this process at all.

Comment: There is no need at all for the contained object to be a power of two. None. Only the buffer size has that limitation. And that `sizeof` is involved, because the question is how to calculate a valid buffer size given an already defined struct.

Comment: @Ext3h: The variable is called "uboAlignment", not "uboSize". So the question is how to align the buffer, not how big it is. That, or the variable is poorly named.

Comment: From my tests on Nvidia cards minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment is 64 so it fits perfectly for mat4 size. But I don't like the fact it can't be less than that as some of the structures I want to upload to UBO are smaller.

Comment: In case anyone else has been confused, it is simply a matter of a poor variable name. The "dynamicAlignment" is actually supposed to be the size necessary to store a uniform buffer object such that the alignment requirements across UBOs are met. In other words, it is simply the size of the UBO rounded up to the nearest multiple of the min alignment requirement. This is hardly an "alignment"; as @NicolBolas mentioned, it is a size. Knowing this, the code presented is not broken. For the record, Sascha's example has since changed to use bitwise arithmetic, but it is semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

1.: The buffer size needs to be a multiple of that. And you need to be aware in which part of that buffer you have actually stored something and where you didn't. If your data doesn't exactly fit your buffer, it needs to be larger in multiples.

2.: Your calculation is off. Integer arithmetics. The result is just 256.

3.: No need to copy the parts of the buffer which don't actually contain your data. Partial copies are allowed, just the buffer itself is bigger.